# Permission denied raised from decorator django

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I have an Image model that has a user field foreignkey from django user

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #more specific model fields
```

I want media files to be served only to users that are logged in and uploaded the media. So I used X-SendFile header in apache using the following view

```
@owns_media
def media_xsendfile(request, path):
    print "inside media_xsendfile view"
    print os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,path)
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type']=''
    response['X-Sendfile']= smart_str(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path))
    return response
```

The owns_media is a decorator that checks if the user logged in is the user that has uploaded the picture and permitts the view to run or raise a PermissionDenied exception. This is the decorator

```
def owns_media(view):
    """Decorator to check if users has permission to access media"""
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        path = kw['path']
        user = request.user
        image = Image.objects.get(image=path)
        image_user = image.user
        if user==image_user:
            return view(request, *args, **kw)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
    return wrapper
```

But it won't work. I loggedn in to a user got the picture, then logged out and tried to access it and it did serve the picture while it shouldn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try printing the values of `image_user` and `user`?

Comment: I keep forgetting I need to restart apache...:(...Once restarted worked like a charm

Comment: If you're doing development, why don't you use the Django development server?  That will restart automatically for you when you change your code.

Comment: True but I am getting prepared on setting it up so setting it up on my apache and then I will deploy it.